# Continuous calls to Ajax Modal Popup makes page slow

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I am using Ajax modal popup on a page. This can be called n number of time. 
Steps are:

1. User opens the Modal popup.
2. Do some server things.
3. Fire OK server event. This will also hide() the modal popup.

After repeting these steps almost 5 - 10 times, it makes page very slow.

I have also called dispose() method of modal popup while hiding(). But it still makes page very slow. Page has a scrollbar, while scrolling, I can identifies how much page gets slower.

Once I refresh the page, then it becomes fine.

Comment: How do you open the Modal Popup ? Are you sure you don't open() a new every time ?

Comment: I am calling the modalPopup.Show() method from server side. I have to call this method at many places as well once modal popup has been shown, after every server event on modal popup.

Comment: I've noticed that if you have a modal popup on a page that has a grid or repeater or a large set of data that binds on PostBack, it will be slow because calling the Show Method posts back the page.